# CSS SVG opacity iOS issue

Tags: html, css, image, svg, opacity

I just did a web-site and for a certain wrapper i'm using

`background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' viewBox='0 0 100 100' preserveAspectRatio='none'%3E%3Cpolygon points='0,100 100,0 100,100' style='fill:rgba(248,0,0,0.63)' /%3E%3C/svg%3E");`

now the opacity effect works perfectly on the desktop and android browser.

However for iOS (both iphone and ipad) the color becomes solid.

Which removes the entire effect designed for the website

Thanks for any input :)

Answer (score 2):

Try to add

```
visibility: visible;
```

to the element.

It's answer I have found here: http://www.punkchip.com/css-opacity-not-working-in-ios/

Comment: Correct - strangely it doesnt happen on my iphone 12pro (safari) - but it does on a testing iphone 14 (also safari), all the latest versions

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about markup you have provided at all. However, if it works, something like this may work for the opacity maybe.

```
polygon points='0,100 100,0 100,100' style='fill:rgba(248,0,0,0.63)'
```

change to

```
polygon points='0,100 100,0 100,100' fill='rgb(240,0,0)' fill-opacity='0.63'
```

Comment: and when you use fill='rgb(240,0,0)' ?

Comment: just applied it to the code and the issue still remains